# Use the main search field to search a SharePoint list for entries in "Person or Group" type column

Tags: untagged

**Setting:** SharePoint online project staff list contains *person or group* column as well as bunch of metadata columns about that person.

**Problem:** Main search field at the top of the page with "Search this list" written in it does't return anything from the list ... ever. I need it to return results only from the person column. Applying filter to column for a person that is 100% on that list returns empty list half of the time.

I **really** miss the desktop experience  Please help.